# onClick() not Called Until Further Input

Tags: android, listview

I have a fancy ExpandableListView that I ripped off from some tutorial. The ListView's expanded state has two elements: a TextView and a Button.
My issue is that, on some rows, onClick() doesn't fire the first time I click the Button. It seems to get called after any other user input, like scrolling or collapsing the row.

Here's a snippet of my ListView inflation:

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/response_title"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/lightred"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp" />

    <com.flare.manual.ExpandingLayout
        android:id="@+id/response_expanding_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:visibility="gone" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/response_body"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fontFamily="serif"
            android:paddingBottom="20dp"
            android:paddingLeft="15dp"
            android:paddingRight="15dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/response_btn_more"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/manual_btn_more" />
    </com.flare.manual.ExpandingLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

I have an Adapter that sets the onClickListener as well:

```
buttonMore.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Log.i("Test", "Item clicked: " + titleView.getText());
    }
});
```

Can anyone help?